# Command to get information about a mp3 using ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Is there a command with ffmpeg that returns information about an mp3 like the bitrate or sampling frequency?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can try:

```
ffmpeg -i filename
```

Comment: This command will go in and out of the warning below "At least one output file must be specified".  using this will not "ffprobe -i filename"

Answer (score 33):

There is a `ffprobe`.

Simple usage:

```
ffprobe foo.mp3 2>&1 | grep -A1 Duration:
```

will give you output (without displaying any extra window) like:

```
  Duration: 00:03:10.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -i foo.mp3 2>&1 | grep -A1 Duration:` works too!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
$ mpg123 -t example.mp3 2>&1 | grep -A1 -E "^MPEG"
MPEG 2.5 L III cbr32 11025 mono
```

- Notice `cbr32` stand for (*stream*) `constant bit rate`, here at 32 kbps.
- And `11025` is the *Sample Rate*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of "Michał Šrajer" (use of command `ffmpeg -i foo.mp3 2>&1 | grep -A1 Duration:`) works well but the windows users must use <findstr "Duration: Stream"> instead of <grep -A1 Duration:> command, because of differences between Grep and Findstr commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is an opensource and free "[exiftool](https://exiftool.org/)" program that can help you, better than ffmpeg and ffprobe.

```
exiftool filename.mp3
```

so you can change some properties and metadata by exiftool, such as rotation, orientation and very other properies on any mp3, jpg, mp4 and many other file formats.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaInfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaInfo) - command line utility to display information about audio/video files

```bash
alok@alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx:~$ mediainfo -i ~/backup/samsung-f23-20231014/Recordings/Voice\ Recorder/Voice\ 001.m4a 
General
Complete name                            : /home/alok/backup/samsung-f23-20231014/Recordings/Voice Recorder/Voice 001.m4a
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : 3GPP Media Release 4
Codec ID                                 : 3gp4 (isom/3gp4)
File size                                : 130 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 h 19 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 131 kb/s
Performer                                : Galaxy F23 5G
Encoded date                             : UTC 2023-08-25 10:42:59
Tagged date                              : UTC 2023-08-25 10:42:59
ampl                                     : ur
book                                     : bkmk
com.android.version                      : 13

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 2 h 19 min
Source duration                          : 2 h 19 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 128 MiB (98%)
Source stream size                       : 128 MiB (98%)
Title                                    : SoundHandle
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2023-08-25 10:42:59
Tagged date                              : UTC 2023-08-25 10:42:59
mdhd_Duration                            : 8358584
```

[ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) - ffprobe media prober

```bash
alok@alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx:~$ ffprobe -i ~/backup/samsung-f23-20231014/Recordings/Voice\ Recorder/Voice\ 001.m4a 
ffprobe version 5.1.2-3ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-14ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-libsmbclient
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/alok/backup/samsung-f23-20231014/Recordings/Voice Recorder/Voice 001.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2023-08-25T10:42:59.000000Z
    com.android.version: 13
  Duration: 02:19:18.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 130 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-08-25T10:42:59.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```